# Javascript in Wordpress page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, mouseover

I want to run the following javascript in a **Wordpress** page.
Thus, I copied the script as it is directly into the source code of a page. The images are all displayed, but the "mouse over" effect is not working..

I tested the script embedded (directly as code) in a normal html page and it works perfectly.

Help and ideas greatly appreciated!

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                var imgArray = new Array(
                    'pic1.jpg',
                    'pic2.jpg',
                    'pic3.jpg',
                    'pic4.jpg',
                    'pic5.jpg'
                );

                function swapImage(imgID) {
                    var theImage = document.getElementById('theImage');
                    var newImg;
                    newImg = imgArray[imgID];
                    theImage.src = newImg;
                }

                function preloadImages() {      
                    for(var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
                        var tmpImg = new Image;
                        tmpImg.src = imgArray[i];
                    }
                }
            </script>


            <div id="image">
                <img id="theImage" src="images/pic1.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>

            <div id="thumbs">
                <img src="images/pic1_tn.jpg" alt="" onmouseover="swapImage(0);" />
                <img src="images/pic2_tn.jpg" alt="" onmouseover="swapImage(1);" />
                <img src="images/pic3_tn.jpg" alt="" onmouseover="swapImage(2);" />
                <img src="images/pic4_tn.jpg" alt="" onmouseover="swapImage(3);" />
                <img src="images/pic5_tn.jpg" alt="" onmouseover="swapImage(4);" />
                <br />

            </div>
```

Comment: Try putting the javascript in the `<head>` which is located in `header.php`, typically.

Comment: ..and it works :) Thank you! What was the issue here?

Comment: I don't know Wordpress, but maybe it strips `<script>` tags out of content pages?